# Does this follow from congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Let a and b be two distinct prime numbers and x and y are integers. Is the following true?

($x \equiv y \mod a$) and ($x \equiv y \mod b$). So, $a|(x-y)$ and $b|(x-y)$. This means $x-y=ab\phi$ with $\phi \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Can I state the last part or do I need to prove that somehow? It seems logical enough to me but it might be wrong. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @peterwhy I meant a and b, sorry.

Comment: According to [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), there is exactly one $n \pmod {ab}$ that satisfies $(x-y)\equiv n \pmod {ab}$, and from the given condition $0$ does satisfy $(x-y)\equiv 0\pmod{ab}$.

Comment: given two numbers a and b if a|c and b|c then lcm(a,b)|c.For two distinct primes a and b the lcm is ab.so ab|c.here c is x-y

Comment: Do you know Euclid's Lemma: $\,a\mid bn\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid n\ $ for $\,a,b\,$ coprime (or the special case $a,b$ distinct primes)?  That's all you need here to deduce that $\,ab\mid n,\,$ i.e. *lcm = product for coprimes*.  This is used in the uniqueness proof of the CRT solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x-y = am = bn$, $m, n\in \mathbb Z$.

$$am = bn$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $a \mid bn$, $a\mid n$. Let $n = a\phi$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $a$ and $b$ are coprime?